# Why does videojs not work only in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, cross-browser, video.js

I'm using video.js in React. My problem is that video doesn't work only in Chrome. Video loads, but doesn't play automatically. It works in Firefox, Microsoft Edge, even Internet Explorer. The video starts in Chrome only when I have developer tools opened. Have you ever had a problem like this? My code is very simple:

```
<video data-setup='{"loop": true, "autoplay": true, "loadingSpinner": false}' 
className="video-js vjs-default-skin article-video">
    <source src={this.state.video}/>
</video>
```

State loads different videos based on innerWidth.

EDIT:

Attribute muted allows Chrome to autoplay video:

```
<video muted="muted" data-setup='{"loop": true, "autoplay": true, "loadingSpinner": false}' 
className="video-js vjs-default-skin article-video">
    <source src={this.state.video}/>
</video>
```

Comment: I think this issue is related to yours https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5469. If not you should open a new one directly on Github as you seams to have an issue with the library itself and not with your code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please describe what actually happens in Chrome. If the video is shown based on `innerWidth` perhaps opening the devtools just triggers a width that does work. Try resizing the window without opening the devtools and see if the video loads for some sizes.

Comment: Video is shown based on innerWidth, but I'm not using any onChange function. It just loads one time. Resizing the window doesn't change anything.

Comment: @john You are allowed to answer your own question. So you can add the solution as an answer. This makes it easier for others having this issue to find the answer, while you enjoy the reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, chrome is preventing auto play in html5 video, so by default they will not allow auto play. [Read more about the change here...](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Here are their policies on autoplay:

> Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:
>
> - Muted autoplay is always allowed.
> - Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
>   - User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>   - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been    crossed, meaning the user has previously play video with sound.
>   - On mobile, the user has [added the site to their home screen].
> - Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow    autoplay with sound.

As to why autoplay is enabled with the developer tools open: This vaguely answers it :

> Developer switches
>
> As a developer, you may want to change Chrome
> autoplay policy behavior locally to test your website depending on
> user engagement.
>
> - You can decide to disable entirely the autoplay policy by setting the
>   Chrome flag "Autoplay Policy" to "No user gesture is required" at
>   chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy. This allows you to test your website
>   as if user were strongly engaged with your site and playback autoplay
>   would be always allowed.
> - You can also decide to make sure playback autoplay is never allowed by disabling use of MEI, applying autoplay policy to Web Audio, and
>   whether sites with the highest overall MEI get playback autoplay by
>   default for new users. This can be done with three internal switches
>   with
>
>   ***chrome.exe --disable-features=PreloadMediaEngagementData,AutoplayIgnoreWebAudio, MediaEngagementBypassAutoplayPolicies.***

Comment: The OP did not specify that the video loads but not automatically playing. Also, is this behavior affected by opening the devtools as the OP describes?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Video loads, but doesn't play automatically. But... why autoplay works, when developer tools are opened?

Comment: @John Please add these details to the question.

Comment: @Boaz I added details.

Comment: @Platinum Industries Thanks, it helped me a lot. I found a way to disable it by adding attribute muted="muted" to video.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding following attribute to video tag:

```
data-setup='{"fluid": true, "autoplay":true,"html5": {"vhs": 
{"overrideNative": true}, "nativeAudioTracks": false, "nativeVideoTracks": false}}'
```

This causes everything to use the non-native player.